# Upload SVG image in xcode issue

Tags: swift, xcode, svg

Having issue in the upload svg images to the assets.xcassets folder in xcode.
[image]

Comment: What version of Xcode 12 ßeta you use (since it's a new feature). Is it up to date? Is there any mention of issue in the release notes?

Comment: Version 11.5 (11E608c)@Larme

Comment: I don't understand. SVG import is only available in Xcode 12. You are using a Xcode 11.5. It's not possible with that version. And Xcode introduced in your project  new features not supported with your Xcode version. Did you use Xcode 12 at some point?

Answer (score 0):

SVG is supported only in Xcode 12, in Xcode 11 you have to convert svg to pdf